# declaring a typescript type within a class

Tags: typescript

I have a class that has some pretty complicated types based on the generics passed to the class.  I use these same types in a few places and I'm trying to figure out how to make them reusable:

```
class Foo<T> {
  method(): SomeComplicateType<T> {}
  method2(): SomeComplicateType<T> {}
}
```

The only thing I can come up with is this, but it allows the user to overwrite the type which I don't want:

```
class Foo<T, U=SomeComplicatedType<T>> {
  method(): U {}
  method2(): U {}
}
```

Comment: This is discussed in [Microsoft/TypeScript#7061](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7061); there's no official solution but there are several workarounds in there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for this obvious suggestion but you could use an alias:

```
type NiceName<T> = SomeComplicateType<T>

class Foo<T> {
  method(): NiceName<T> {}
  method2(): NiceName<T> {}
}
```

Comment: No suggestions are bad :)  This does make it a bit better and is what I have now, but it's still not the best writing `NiceName<BLAH, FOO, BAR, BAZ>` (I don't like `T, U, V` in this case since I can barely follow the logic, lol)

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript doesn't allow type creation between the two scopes:

```
class A<Scope1> {
  x():Scope2;
}
```

## Your solution

What you have found is a way to create it as a chain in `Scope1`.

## Thoughts

Personally I would bite the bullet and not try to create a new type. I prefer explicit work whenever possible.